# Reversing the colors in an image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, image-sprite

Being quite honest, I couldn't think of a better way to phrase a title for this, so I apologize for that.. Anyway, this is what I need.

I have this image 
[image]

Basically, I need to make the black = white and the white(bell + glow)= black. So basically reverse the colors, so that I can use it in a sprite.

I know there has to be a quick way to do this.

Comment: did you try http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-editing/color-replacement-tool/

Comment: I didn't, but I was looking for the effect that was already built in photoshop, as the answer below showed it. But this is also a valid way to do it, just not what I was looking for. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Image > Adjustments > Invert`

You'll have to address the black shadow independently however. You could remove the shadow, invert then create a new shadow. Or you could select just the circle, and then invert.

The keyboard shortcut is Ctl/Cmd-I.

Comment: I knew there was an easy way of doing this! I was googling the wrong word (reversing , instead of inverting) Thanks man

Comment: "Never answer before Scott!"

Comment: Hogwash.. always answer if you have an answer :)

Comment: @Scott let's see how does it work - http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28919/how-to-adjust-two-handles-equally

Comment: I would've posted Ctrl+I. You're a lot more considerate.

Comment: I just did Ctrl+I after I cut the black background and got a very interested effect our of it. I like it!. You should post that as answer since it did help me. I gave the answer to @Scott, but I'll give yours a like for sure

Comment: Ctrl-I is the same as choosing `Image > Adjustments > Invert`. It's just the keyboard shortcut for it.

Answer (score -1):

You can visit [Photo editor Online Which is Free](http://www.toolpic.com)
this website has a redy made option to reversing the color .